# Need to display customized error messages on the login screen of SPA

Tags: angularjs, spring-security

Working with AngularJS frontend and spring security , need to show meaningful error messages on the login screen.

By searching some posts I came to know that implementing AuthenticationFailureHandler we can create meaningful messages and show them
on the login screen

My doubt is how to link these message from server to client(AngularJS) , I mean
how to display them on angularjs, most of the posts I reffered are not using
AngularJS as frontend.

please help me

Comment: so you need angular code? or server side code

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal, angular code please